# ValueError in broadcasting input array shape

Tags: python

This is the code for gaussian filter blur with 2 functions Gaussianblur and convolution.
Input image has shape (352,640).
The error which is shown is **Value Error** in which there is a problem in broadcasting the given input array.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-40e9111f67c6> in <module>()
----> 1 GaussianBlurImage(noise_img, 0.1)

<ipython-input-35-4c788ece850a> in GaussianBlurImage(image, sigma)
     17     im_filtered = np.zeros_like(image, dtype=np.float32)
     18     for c in range(3):
---> 19         im_filtered[:, :,c] = convolution(image[:, :,c], gaussian_filter)
     20     return (im_filtered.astype(np.uint8))

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (352,0) into shape (352,640)
```

```
def convolution(oldimage, kernel):
    #image = Image.fromarray(image, 'RGB')
    image_h = oldimage.shape[0]
    image_w = oldimage.shape[1]


    kernel_h = kernel.shape[0]
    kernel_w = kernel.shape[1]

    if(len(oldimage.shape) == 3):
        image_pad = np.pad(oldimage, pad_width=((kernel_h // 2, kernel_h // 2),(kernel_w // 2,kernel_w // 2),(0,0)), mode='constant',constant_values=0).astype(np.float32)  



    elif(len(oldimage.shape) == 2):
        image_pad = np.pad(oldimage, pad_width=((kernel_h // 2, kernel_h // 2),(kernel_w // 2,kernel_w // 2)), mode='constant', constant_values=0).astype(np.float32) 



    h = kernel_h // 2
    w = kernel_w // 2

    image_conv = np.zeros(image_pad.shape)

    for i in range(h, image_pad.shape[0]-h):
        for j in range(w, image_pad.shape[1]-w):
            #sum = 0
            x = image_pad[i-h:i-h+kernel_h, j-w:j-w+kernel_w]
            x = x.flatten()*kernel.flatten()
            image_conv[i][j] = x.sum()
    h_end = -h
    w_end = -w

    if(h == 0):
        return image_conv[h:,w:w_end]
    if(w == 0):
        return image_conv[h:h_end,w:]
    return image_conv[h:h_end,w:w_end]
```

Code for Gaussian Blur

```
def GaussianBlurImage(image, sigma):
    # image = imread(image)
    # image = Image.open(image)
    # image = np.asarray(image)
    #print(image)
    filter_size = 2 * int(4 * sigma + 0.5) + 1
    gaussian_filter = np.zeros((filter_size, filter_size), np.float32)
    m = filter_size//2
    n = filter_size//2

    for x in range(-m, m+1):
        for y in range(-n, n+1):
            x1 = 2*np.pi*(sigma**2)
            x2 = np.exp(-(x**2 + y**2)/(2* sigma**2))
            gaussian_filter[x+m, y+n] = (1/x1)*x2

    im_filtered = np.zeros_like(image, dtype=np.float32)
    for c in range(3):
        im_filtered[:, :,c] = convolution(image[:, :,c], gaussian_filter)
    return (im_filtered.astype(np.uint8))
```

Please help me to solve the error.
Thanks

Comment: In the return statement of `convolution`, I suspect that the slice `w:wend` does not include any indices. So the returned array has one dimension of 0, and numpy will fail broadcasting it

Comment: What do you suggest to overcome the following problem?